# Unity 2d NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am getting this error:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object Obstacle.OnTriggerEnter2D (UnityEngine.Collider2D collision) (at Assets/Scripts/Obstacle.cs:22)

There is no problem in the code. Where am I making a mistake?

[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSKoS.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSDkt.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRHdO.png)

Please help.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please make sure to check out the guide to ask good questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Regarding your error, it's very likely caused by the misspelling of the method `Start` as `start` (mind the capital S) in Obstacle.cs

Comment: Welcome to SO! As @EduardoPáezRubio stated above, please check out [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). For the sake of everyone who is going to see this question, please *do not* post code/errors/instructions in the form of images. Please copy and paste it into your question and format it properly.

Comment: If you are getting exception than `There is no problem in the code.` is usually a quite bold statement ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue caused by a small typo in the form of a lowercase ‘s’ instead of an uppercase ‘S’.

Because the Unity Engine was looking for `Start` and couldn’t find it, your “start” code never ran. Because of that, your `Player` was never assigned to, and had a “null reference”. And that’s why when you tried to read the tag, for a reference that was null, you got the error.

Your code should be:

```cs
private void Start ()
{
    ..
}
```

Note the exact case for `Start` and all C# commands.